# Gravitational potential energy with both bodies moving

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, potential-energy, inertial-frames

When deducing the formula for the gravitational potential energy of one body in relation to the gravitational force of another body, my teacher assumed that one body was standing still. I tried deriving it without that assumption, but did not succeed. How do I do it?

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Perhaps you could go into more detail about what you have tried and what you are specifically hung up on.

Comment: Thank you, i just don't know how to type in Latex yet. Anyway, by definition, i have to calculate the integral of (Gm1m2/(r1-r2)^2)dr1. Taking out of the integrand the constants, i have: Gm1m2* integral  of (1/(r1-r2)^2)dr1. And, as i said, my teacher supposed that r2 was constant to evaluate the integral (body (2) is standing still). If, however, i do not make that assumption, how do i go forward?

Comment: Why do you want to derive it without that assumption?

Comment: When you make that assumption, you are basically considering a reference frame where body 2 is stationary, which is not a very general case. By allowing r2 to not be constant, i would be generalizing the expression for the potential energy for any reference frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding about gravitational potential energy. It does not belong to a single body, but to a system of bodies. The gravitational potential energy is independent of the paths that bodies take, and only depends only on their separation distances of their centers of mass. It matters not if they are moving or at rest. Relative motion means that the potential energy of the system will be changing, but the value of the potential energy depends on their positions.

The reason you do an integral to derive the formula $$G\frac{m_1 m_2}{|\vec{r_1}-\vec{r_2}|}$$ is to calculate the work done by the gravitational force in moving the masses from an infinite separation to a finite separation. The potential energy of the system is the negative of that work.

Comment: ''The gravitational potential energy is independent of the paths that bodies take, and only depends only on their separation distances of their centers of mass''. I agree that the force of gravity will only depend on their center of masses distances. But, from my understanding, the potential energy will depend on your reference frame. If you choose the reference frame of body 2 (back to my examples) you will get the minus the integral of (Gm1m2/r^2)dr as the potential energy. But if you consider a more general reference frame, you get the equation as i put it.

Comment: @victormd Are you incorporating length contraction from SR? If not, I don't see how your frame of reference changes the distance between the masses at any point in time.

Comment: The distance between the masses doesn't change (and, thus, their force), but their velocity will (depending on the reference frame) and, since the expression for potential energy is: - integral of (-Gm1m2/((r1-r2)^2)dr1). The infinitesimal dr1 will make a difference on the resulting integral depending on the reference frame.

Comment: @victormd I have no idea what you mean by "a more general reference frame." There is no general reference frame. And as Aaron  Stevens asks, are you talking about SR effects?  As stated in my answer, the potential energy is *defined* by the work done by the force in moving from a reference configuration to a different configuration. One could move both masses and the result would be the same.